# How to convert an image into an m by n matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, imread

I have an image and I want to do some calculation on it so I need its matrix form. When I read my image using `imread('image.png')`, MATLAB give an `M*N*3` matrix which is not wrong since these three dimension are for colors. However, I need an `M*N` matrix.

How can I convert this `M*N*3` matrix into an `M*N` matrix with a true colormap?

Comment: What calculations? You might get some weird results if they're performed on an indexed image

Comment: That's why I want to have an `M*N` matrix instead of an `M*N*3` matrix

Comment: Why not work on the RGB? (you can handle each channel separately if required). Most operations don't work on indexed images properly, and converting to grey scale will lose information.

Comment: Working each of those three separately is not good for my work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[X,map] = rgb2ind(RGB,n)`
where RGB is the image you have read, n is the maximum number of colors, X is the new image, and map is the colormap.

You can also use `[X,map] = imread('Image.png');`

Comment: But how can I find the appropriate `n` to produce the same color as my image.png ?